# How to update a field using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have updated my question to reflect what the comments below have helped me understand. My view is not passing the ID of the current location over so that is why it is null. In my table I include the location ID in the route. My updated question would be how would I go about passing that ID that is in the route back over when I submit my form?

Service layer:

```
public Location GetById(int id)
{
     var location = _context.Locations.Where(l => l.Id == id)
            .Include(l => l.User)
            .FirstOrDefault();

     return location;
}

public async Task UpdateLocationAddress(int locationId, string newAddress)
{
    var location = GetById(locationId);
    location.Address = newAddress;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Model:

```
public class UpdateLocationModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Update()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateLocation(int id, string newAddress)
{
   await _locationService.UpdateLocationAddress(id, newAddress);
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location");
}
```

Table where you click address to go to form to update:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="locationIndexTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Delete Location</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var location in Model.LocationList)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a asp-controller="Location" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="@location.Id">
                @location.Name
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-controller="Location" asp-action="Update" asp-route-id="@location.Id"> @location.Address</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @location.PhoneNumber
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary delete-link">Delete</a>
            <a asp-controller="Location" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@location.Id" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm delete-confirm" style="display:none">Confirm Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

View where you update the address on the form and post - Should update address

```
@model HealthEval.Models.Location.LocationModel

<h1>Update Location</h1>

<form asp-action="UpdateLocation" method="post" id="updateAddressForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address"></label>
        <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submitLocationBtn" class="btn btn-submitLocation">Update Location</button>
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

And finally my error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
public async Task UpdateLocationAddress(int locationId, string newAddress)
{
    var location = GetById(locationId);
    location.Address = newAddress; <-- error highlights here
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateLocation(int id, string newAddress)
{
    await _locationService.UpdateLocationAddress(id, newAddress);<--error
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location");
}
```

I may be over-complicating this process so any help is appreciated!

LocationModel Class

```
    namespace HealthEval.Models.Location
{
    public class LocationModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `location` is null because `GetById` is returning a null object.

Comment: Check out the MVC Movie tutorial -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @gertArnold Yeah I was thinking a lot of the code was irrelevant but I'm new to this and didn't want to leave anything out.

Comment: @CoreyBryant I have answered your question point by point. Follow my answer, hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **controller**, rename and update your `Update()` get method to `UpdateLocation()` as follows:

Don't forget to change `Update.cshtml` view file name to `UpdateLocation.cshtml` as well.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateLocation(int id)
{
    Location locationToBeUpdated =  await _locationService.GetById(id);
    return View(locationToBeUpdated);
}
```

**Then in the view:**

```
@model Location
<h1>Update Location</h1>

<form asp-action="UpdateLocation" method="post" id="updateAddressForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Address"></label>
        <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submitLocationBtn" class="btn btn-submitLocation">Update Location</button>
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Then your **Controller's** `UpdateLocation()` post method parameter name is `newAddress` but your input filed name is `address` and that's why parameter value is also getting null during post action. so modify the `UpdateLocation()` post method also as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateLocation(int id, string address)
{
   await _locationService.UpdateLocationAddress(id, address);
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Location");
}
```

**Then in the Location Service**

```
public async Task UpdateLocationAddress(int locationId, string newAddress)
{
    Location locationToBeUpdated = GetById(locationId);
    if(locationToBeUpdated != null)
    {
     locationToBeUpdated .Address = newAddress;
     wait _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Hope now it will work as expected!

Comment: Hey! Thank you for all of this. I am getting this error:                                            The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'HealthEval.Data.Models.Location', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'HealthEval.Models.Location.LocationModel'.

Comment: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'HealthEval.Data.Models.Location', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'HealthEval.Models.Location.LocationModel'.

Comment: Okay! Got it. This is very simple error to fix. You should fix it. Please add your Location Model classes in the question.

Comment: Please post your UpdateLocation.cshtml file's full code here.

Comment: I added the locationModel class into the question

Comment: added full cshtml in question I don't know how to format comments

Comment: Got it! Where is your Location class?

Comment: My location class is in a data layer and it looks like this `using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace HealthEval.Data.Models
{
    public class Location
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }
    }
}`

Comment: Ohhhhh I see what you mean. Man I am dumb!

Comment: Awesome your code works! I'm going to study it now to figure out how it is working! Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: Glad to see your problem has been solved! Thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the location IDs are unique.

In `GetLocationById` use `Single()` instead of `FirstOrDefault()` if the location will always exist.

Or use `SingleOrDefault()` and do a `null`-check afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for null before trying to assign a value to an object that doesn't exist.

```
var location = GetById(locationId);
if(location != null)
{
    location.Address = newAddress; <-- error highlights here
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Hope that help but you might also want to look into your GetById method.